# How to frame complex search structures on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, tags, search

I wish to ask questions that are from a certain set of tags, but does not contain certain other set of tags like so:

```
(tag1 or tag2 or tag3) and not(tag4) and not(tag5) and not(tag6)
```

I'm not sure how to do this, I tried

```
[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3] -[tag4] -[tag5] -[tag6]
```

but it's not working out as expected.

To be precise, I search using the following string

```
[python] or [python-2.x] or [python-3.x] -[django] -[angularjs] -[dataframe]
```

But I still get questions with [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe).

Could you anyone kindly provide an alternative?

Comment: The second syntax works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html%20or%20java%20not%20spring%20not%20php - this is after I type `[html] or [java] -[spring] -[php]` in the search box. This might be because I chose very popular tags.

Comment: Can you submit the precise query ? i tryed `[c#] or [java] -[input] -[iis] -[performance]` without any problems

Comment: Sure, @Walfrat, I did so just now.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac thanks, I can reproduce it now.

Comment: @Glorfindel: So... am I missing something or is this just a bug in the search (I sure hope not)?

Comment: Seems like a bug.

Comment: [This bug was raised a few days ago.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337714/filter-questions-that-have-one-of-multiple-tags-and-dont-have-all-of-multiple-t) It is indeed puzzling.

Comment: @Kendra I thought not being able to have -[tag] was an old, known bug. Am I thinking about something else?

Comment: @BSMP I hadn't seen it before that one, so if it is old and known, I missed it. :) -[tag] does work, at least it seems so after some testing I've done, but having more than one with an "or" definitely doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

So I was able to reproduce the problem

By searching

```
[python] or [python-2.x] or [python-3.x] -[django] -[angularjs] -[dataframe]
```

I had a question in my results with [python] & [dataframe]. However moving the [python] tag like this :

```
  [python-2.x] or [python-3.x] or [python] -[django] -[angularjs] -[dataframe]
```

I was able to get rid of that question with [dataframe] tag.

So my guess is that the engine give a priority to AND operator like this :

```
      [python-2.x] or [python-3.x] or ([python] -[django] -[angularjs] -[dataframe])
```

Note : I tried to use

```
 ([python-2.x] or [python-3.x] or [python]) -[django] -[angularjs] -[dataframe]
```

It works, but there is a trap : you get switch from the newest view  to the most relevant(=with the most tags in common), just switch back to the newest and you're good.

Comment: Well, thanks for answering, but your last point is *exactly* the problem I'm facing. That's why I prefer tag-search to general search.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac if you look at the result, you'll see that you can switch back to the newest questions. So it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to not include the dataframe tag.

```
is:q [python] or [python-2.x] or [python-3.x] -[django] -[angularjs] -[dataframe]
```