# New-Nav Search Bar Chopping Tag Filters

Tags: bug, search, new-nav

I recently attempted to create a custom new-nav tab that requires one of multiple tags, yet also excludes multiple tags:
[Filter Questions that have one of multiple tags and don't have all of multiple tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337714/filter-questions-that-have-one-of-multiple-tags-and-dont-have-all-of-multiple-t)

Since I have yet to figured out how to get that to work, I continued to play around with the new-nav tabs and search. I picked a few random tags, and created a tab that uses the following search query:

```
[java] [c#] -[android] -[spark-dataframe] -[unity3d] -[rtf]
```

When I enter this into either the new-nav search bar, or in to the main search bar on top of the site, the new-tab search bar results to the following:

> [image]

As you can see, half of the tags are cut off. One tag is even cut off in middle.

There is definitely something really wrong going on here.

I was able to recreate this bug in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Kendra Looks like that might be the same problem. That question was asked 4 months ago though and never received any response and barely any views.

Comment: Yes, but it's still the same issue, so still a duplicate. The team's been a bit slow to get to new-nav bugs lately. Best to go ahead and tie them together for when they go to fix it and mark bugs as completed.