# What is the current status of the new tabbed tags navigation?

Tags: support, new-nav

Fifteen months have passed since [the last official update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate). There's a bunch of feedback from users awaiting response from the developers. The "opt-in" setting on the profile page still says that it is a "beta feature".

What's the current status of this project? Are you still looking for feedback from us? Has it been abandoned?

Comment: I've been using it for a long time by now and thought that it has been finally released a long time ago...

Comment: I've been wondering this off and on for months. I've got an open bug on new-nav that's driving me nuts, and if it's not going to be touched in the foreseeable future, I'd at least like to know that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [in this revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/308875/14) of the mentioned update post, development of the new navigation is currently on hold:

> Administrative Note July 6, 2017: development for this project is currently on hold; if you find it useful you may continue to use it and report bugs or suggestions, but fixes / improvements may not be forthcoming.

Answer (score 6):

It's in a bit of a state of flux because a lot of things that were being built independently of it have a bit of influence on what we finally settle on. It's still available for testing, and all of the feedback has been tremendously helpful, but I'm not sure how much it's going to move until we have a pretty solid (as in a very solid spec) of what additional functionality it's going to need to have.

There may be new relevancy controls, where you can do a much better job of filtering out questions that really *don't* interest you. There may be a mentorship program being conceptualized where you might want to optimize for questions from new users that seem good, *just barely* fall off the unanswered list, where we can pick up that the OP still seems to have interest in more answers.

Then there's the whole new top nav we're testing, and we have to see how that's all going to blend together UX wise, and we still have to tackle some things related to moderators having quite a bit more functionality than everyone else, and trying to improve the tools they use to find places that need their attention.

So as soon as we get all of that wrapped in (or at least finally know what we're going to need to account for), we'll start putting it all together. Probably .. 3 - 6 months at the soonest before we're near ready.

I will check into open bugs, I know we thought we were to the point where we fixed everything that outright blocked usability, but I'll have a look. Can't promise though, because until we're sure what we're keeping out of it, some things might be moot. I'll do my best to get [status-wontfix](/questions/tagged/status-wontfix) on those.

Comment: Good to finally see an update. I was starting to worry it'd just been completely ditched. :)

Comment: @Kendra I .. somehow didn't have all of the current information. This might actually ship very soon.

Comment: FYI one thing that still doesn't work is the back button: go to page two, open a question, click back: you're now on page one again, and not page two. Other than that, I find it works very well and miss it one sites that don't have it (i.e. all other sites).

Comment: @TimPost This isn't the only new-nav bug I have raised, yet the bug where [tags are sometimes chopped off](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338017/new-nav-search-bar-chopping-tag-filters) is pretty bad for usability and should probably be looked into.

Comment: Yeah, somehow wires got crossed here, any movement here is still months away (there's a ton of chatter internally about the new top nav and this got swooped up in it and it was 3:30 AM and I got confused) Sorry about that!